# Microsoft Teams PWA - get notice when meeting starts

Tags: google-chrome, notification, microsoft-teams

So Microsoft Teams is discontinuing support of the native Linux app.

Currently we are using the PWA in Chrome browser. This works pretty well, but I don't get a popup notification when someone starts a meeting.

Notifications seem to be switched all on in teams.

Is there way to get such notifications?

Or do we have to risk Ubuntu users to be known as always late for or missing meetings? ;-))

Comment: I doubt there is any method from within Ubuntu that will let you do this. You need the native app or a spin-off of this native app or a chrome extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show a popup notification when a person joins a meeting, I use [Teams for Linux](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux). It is an

> Unofficial Microsoft Teams client for Linux using Electron. It uses the Web App and wraps it as a standalone application using Electron.

To install: use the script, snap or flatpack on their [GitHub](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux) (I used [deb-get](https://github.com/wimpysworld/deb-get/tree/main) for simplicity).

```bash
sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/keyrings/teams-for-linux.asc https://repo.teamsforlinux.de/teams-for-linux.asc
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/teams-for-linux.asc arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] https://repo.teamsforlinux.de/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams-for-linux-packages.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install teams-for-linux
```

Small note: The behavior is different than Windows. On Windows you also get a notification at the time the meeting is scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell Rinzwind is right that there is no Ubuntu specific way to do this. You need to either use the [Teams Notification Alert](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/teams-notification-alert/mnhjkbmimdpecnhoacaflgbbihdipjde?hl=en) extension, or else rely on another method of receiving notifications, like email.

Comment: That seems to go in the right direction. Will see if there are better options, the extension seems a bit strange, as you always have to keep it's window open. I think I will also give https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux a second try.

Answer (score 0):

Along with other answer, when you have no Outlook on Linux, you may want to use Thunderbird for email and its Calendar for notifications.